# Unable to enable ext-gmp

Tags: php, php-extension, gmp

So I've been trying to enable `gmp` on my macbook pro, but upto no avail.

Here's what I've done till now.

1. Uncommented `extension=php_gmp.dll` in `/private/etc/php.ini`
2. Uncommented `extension=php_gmp.dll` in `/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini`
   (coonfiguration file as displayed in phpinfo() )
3. phpinfo()  says gmp is enabled, but when I do `php -m`, it doesnt
   shows gmp.

What must I do?

Answer (score 1):

The lines that you're uncommenting are examples. The extension is not actually present on your system -- you need to install the extension before you can enable it.

The easiest way of doing this will probably be to install the extension through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). If you have Homebrew installed, you can install the extension by running `brew install php72-gmp`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right in your third point, you arr probably only editing the php.ini for web server usage and not the one to be used for CLI? You can find that second ini file through `php -i | grep ini`