# Composer error - GMP

Tags: composer-php, gmp

While i want to install composer I have error:

[image]

I have installed GMP on my mac - i see it in folder + while i use "brew search gmp" i see checkmark. So its all all right.

I have also enabled in php.ini

```
extension=gmp.so
extension=php_gmp.so
```

I really don't what to do. I can't find those two files in GMP folder or anywhere in my mac. `phpinfo` or `php -m` don't see GMP loaded

Comment: If `php -m` does not show GMP, you have not installed it properly. How did you install it? Probably like explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47950495/unable-to-enable-ext-gmp?

Comment: I installed it via `brew install gmp`

Comment: When i use `brew install php72-gmp` it show me an error :
`Error: No available formula with the name "php72-gmp"`

Comment: `brew install gmp` installs only the GMP lib itself, not the connector to PHP. Which PHP version do you currently use?

Comment: i have PHP 7.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your PHP version to v7.1.15 using `brew install php@7.1` which should contain GMP already. They moved some stuff around recently, so the existing solutions got useless